# Connection refused 111 when trying to connect an SMTP server on plesk

Tags: php, request, plesk

I am trying to submit a form on my server, But I am failing on this chuck of code (Sorry but I did not write this code, bit was asked to embed it -

```
$fp = fsockopen('212.29.198.85', 1008, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8'));
    fclose($fp);
}
```

The error is

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning:  fsockopen(): unable to connect to
>   212.29.198.85:1008

How can I know if my server is the problem or the addressed server ?

Comment: Are you sure the correct port is 1008? SMTP usually runs on 25, 465, or 587.

Comment: Well I tried to change this but the result is the same, thanks

Answer (score 1):

"Connection refused" may caused by firewall. In other case it should be "Connection timeout"

anyway, check `netstat -anp` to findout which ports are open by which process.

Answer (score -1):

It can help to unblock/whitelist destination IP or disable SMTP blocking/whitelist user in ConfigServerFirewall (if used) configuration:

```
SMTP_BLOCK = off
SMTP_ALLOWUSER = usernamehere
```